# x-axis not updating in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

The general question I have is this: Can you use plt.axis in a for loop such that if a certain condition isn't met then the old axis limits are replaced with the new ones? I have tried this below by having the x-axis set from 0-10 for the first 10 iterations, then set the x-axis as the xmin to xmax thereafter but the plot is not updating properly. Is there something I am missing?

```
from time import sleep
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temperature = []
x = list()
y = list()
y1 = list()
dT_tol = .5

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure(1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
temp_plot = plt.scatter([],[])      
plt.ylabel('Temperature (C)')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
delta_temp_plot = plt.scatter([],[],zorder = 2)
plt.axhspan(-dT_tol, dT_tol, color='#87CEFA', alpha=1, zorder = 1)
plt.ylabel('dT')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')

plt.draw()

# Read loop
for i in range(60):
    tempC = i #for simplicity, I can get real T later
    temperature.append(tempC)
    dT = temperature[i]-temperature[i-1]

    x.append(i)
    y.append(temperature[i])
    y1.append(dT)

    if len(x)>10:
        del x[0]
        del y[0]
        del y1[0]

    xmin = min(x)
    xmax = max(x)   

    if -dT_tol<dT<dT_tol:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT, "         " "Steady State"
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT
        sleep(1)

    #Replace old points with new points
    temp_plot.set_offsets(zip(x,y))
    delta_temp_plot.set_offsets(zip(x,y1))

    if len(x)<=10:
        ax1.axis([0,10,0,80])
        ax2.axis([0,10,0,80])
    else:
        ax1.axis([xmin,xmax,0,80])
        ax2.axis([xmin,xmax,-4,4])

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Your line `if len(x) > 10:` and the next 3 lines of your code deletes the first element of your lists. Therefore later on when you try to update your axes with `if len(x)<=10:` and the next few lines of code, your else statement will never execute as when your lists get greater than 10, you delete the first element.

Comment: oh wow, such a dumb error. I wanted if the value of x<=10, not length of x. Thanks!